# Can't access full iteration of dictionary outside of for loop python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, variables

**The problem**

I am trying to access my `tag_dict` dictionary variable outside of a for loop so I can use that dictionary to learn how to insert that data into sqlite. (First Sqlite project)

If I print the `tag_dict` inside of the for loop it gives me all the data.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from tinytag import TinyTag
import sqlite3
import json


tag = ''
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name))
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
            tag_dict = tag.as_dict()
            #print tag_dict   - This prints everything but I want this outside of the for loop...or how am I going to insert this into my sqlite database?

#print tag_dict   - This prints only one iteration when I need all the data so I can pass it over to an INSERT command in sqlite.... I think
```

Here is the result if I add a `print tag_dict` to the for loop:

```
{'comment': u"Shoot 'em up", 'album': u'Aerostar', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'Stage 7', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Dota Ando', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': u'8-Bit', 'albumartist': u'Dota Ando', 'filesize': 160102674L, 'composer': u'Dota Ando', 'year': u'1991', 'duration': 99.9999, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u'Platformer', 'album': u'Aladin', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'Track 10', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Steve Rockett', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': u'8-Bit', 'albumartist': u'Steve Rockett', 'filesize': 302885452L, 'composer': u'Steve Rockett', 'year': u'2000', 'duration': 180.04653333333334, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u'Platformer', 'album': u'Aladin', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'Track 11', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Steve Rockett', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': u'8-Bit', 'albumartist': u'Steve Rockett', 'filesize': 302791162L, 'composer': u'Steve Rockett', 'year': u'2000', 'duration': 180.04653333333334, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
#there is over 6000 more tracks to get through
```

Here is the result if I add a `print tag_dict` to the outside of the for loop:

```
{'comment': u'Action-adventure', 'album': u'Spawn Armageddon', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': None, 'track': '9', 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Rik Schaffer', 'track_total': '0', 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Rik Schaffer', 'filesize': 75479673L, 'composer': u'Rik Schaffer', 'year': u'2003', 'duration': 49.11573333333333, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
#and that's it. where is the rest of my data? :(
>>>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each iteration of the inner loop, `tag_dict = tag.as_dict()` is setting `tag_dict` to a new value. So, after the loop is finished, the variable only has the final value, and none of the previous values.

If you want to keep all of the values, you could use a list instead, and append `tag.as_dict()` to that list within the loop.

Comment: I tried doing this and I got an error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`. I tried following this link:https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-append-elements-to-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list-in-python but it didn't help much. Do you know how to use append? I have never used this and it doesn't seem to work for dictionaries.

Comment: `tag_dict` is a dictionary and not a list, so you can't call `append` on it. What I'm recommending is doing something like adding `tag_dicts = []` above the loops, and then replacing your current `tag_dict = tag.as_dict()` line with `tag_dicts.append(tag.as_dict())`. Then you'll have a list of all the dictionaries instead of just a single dictionary.

Comment: I "think" this is the answer so I am going to mark it as correct. The reason I "think" its the answer is because when I tried to run the script, its been frozen for while. I have over 6000 songs, I think turning that metadata from an object, then into a dictionary, then into a list is going to take a while.

Comment: hmm that's weird, I wouldn't expect that changing it to use a list would slow it down at all

Comment: Actually your code works, its just that big. hahaha I stopped the code and changed the link to a specific director path instead so I had less results and it totally came up in seconds. lol